# Lightning categorization of a high-speed "ball" of light

Tags: meteorology, lightning

While driving behind the back side of an intense thunderstorm, I saw a lightning phenomenon I haven't seen before - just a bright blueish light at high speed, following an erratic path, just like the path a cloud-to-cloud bolt would trace. There was light ahead and before it for a short distance, trailing off in intensity.

Does this fall into the category of ball lightning, or is it something else?

Comment: This is too thin to say anything definitive.